# Install RocketRaid 644L Raid Controller driver on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hardware-raid

I bought a RocketRaid 644L and get stuck at driver installation.

```
uname -a
Linux hb38-backup 3.2.0-41.generic #66-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.2

lspci
RAID bus controller: HighPoint Technologies, Inc. Device 0645 (rev 01)
```

I down load the driver from [driver list](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_rr600-download.htm), I choose ***Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64***. I just simply type the install commend and reboot the server.

```
cd driver_folder
sudo sh install
```

But when I reboot the server, I the driver actually is not installed correctly, and can't load the disks. But the BIOS can detect those disks, so I think the problem comes from the driver. Does anyone use this kind of Raid controller?

Comment: Did you configure any volumes or anything like that on the RAID controller at boot time?

Comment: Hi Gene, thanks for reply. I didn't do so, because in the boot BIOS stage, it lists the drives, so I assume it can load those drives by firmware, but the Ubuntu can't read them so I think it's driver's problem. And the installation guide doesn't told me to configure the Raid Controller during BIOS. Actually there's only one option during BIOS, it's ctrl + H for help, no configuration options.